# How can Ventury tube measure velocity in a pipe when it is is zero at the wall?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, bernoulli-equation

In the Venturi tube the sum of static and dynamic pressure is kept constant along a streamline. A reduced cross section leads to a reduced static pressure.

$$p_1+\rho v_1^2/2 = p_2 + \rho v_2^2/2$$

But on the other hand, the velocity in a pipe is zero at its wall. So, following a streamline close to the wall, I would get

$$p_1=p_2$$

[image]

How can it still work to measure velocity and which velocity is taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer.** Because pressure is approximately constant across a thin boundary layer.

[image]

**Some details.** You can connect velocity and pressure in different points of a fluid belonging to the same irrotational region (i.e. region where vorticity is zero, $\boldsymbol{\omega}(\mathbf{r},t) = \mathbf{0}$), like the points $A_1$ and $A_2$ in the figure above,
$$\frac{1}{2}\rho V_1^2 + P_{1} = \frac{1}{2}\rho V_2^2 + P_{2} $$.

For sufficiently high, thin boundary layer develops on the walls of the pipe.  Pressure is approximately constant across the boundary layer, as you can derive from some mathematical models of the boundary layer, like Prandtl equations.

Thus, you can say that the pressure measured by the sensors at wall equals the pressure in the irrotational flow at the same sections
$$P_{wall,1} = P_1 \qquad , \qquad P_{wall,2} = P_2 \ .$$

**Some other details - more important than you may think.** The flow shown in the picture of your answer, with the developed Poiseuille **parabolic velocity** profile, is **not irrotational**. Thus you **can't use Bernoulli's theorem!**

Comment: But is the pressure constant over the cross section? Because in the center r=0 we have a much higher velocity as compared to, lets say, r=R/2 . Neither of the two positions are part of the boundary layer. Would I get different static pressures when I measure at those two positions? I would naively say, that  at r=0 there is lower pressure as compared to r=R/2.

Comment: You need irrotational flow: parabolic profile velocity is typical of low Reynolds flow, where viscosity is not negligible, and thus vorticity is not negligible as well: in such a situation, **Bernoulli's theorem DOES NOT HOLD**. Once you're dealing with irrotational flow, you need to place pressure sensors at sections where the flow is approximately uniform, qualitatively sufficiently far from bends on straight regions of the pipe

Comment: aaahhh- this makes sense . Forgot that.